# Arduino and Processing code error "disabling_serialevent()"

Tags: serial-port, arduino, processing

I am facing the following error in a [Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28programming_language%29) application off and on, and sometimes it works perfectly.

> Error, disabling serialEvent() for COM2
>
> null

Here is the code:

Arduino's:

```cpp
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int sensorValue1 = analogRead(A0);
  int sensorValue2 = analogRead(A1);
  Serial.print(sensorValue1);
  Serial.write("-");
  Serial.println(sensorValue2);
  delay(1);
}
```

#### Processing's

```java
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;  // The serial port
void setup () {
  size(1043, 102);
  background(255);
  myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[1], 9600);
  println(Serial.list());
  myPort.bufferUntil('\n');
}

void draw () {
  // Everything happens in the serialEvent()
}

void serialEvent (Serial myPort) {
  background(255);
  String inString = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');
  if (inString != null) {
    inString = trim(inString);
    // String inByte = inString;
    int[] inStr = int(split(inString, '-'));
    println(inStr);

    fill(0);
    rect(10, 2, inStr[0], 46);

    rect(10, 52, inStr[1], 46);

    fill(255);
    rect(400, 14, 245, 21);

    fill(0);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    textSize(14);
    text("1st value: " + inStr[0] + " 2nd value: " + inStr[1], width/2, 30);
  }
}
```

When I remove following part of code, the application works fine.

```cpp
fill(0);
rect(10, 2, inStr[0], 46);

rect(10, 52, inStr[1], 46);

fill(255);
rect(400, 14, 245, 21);

fill(0);
textAlign(CENTER);
textSize(14);
text("1st value: " + inStr[0] + " 2nd value: " + inStr[1], width/2, 30);
```

I am using Windows 7, Processing version 2.2.1, and Arduino version 1.0.5-r2.

I'm new to all serial communication stuff...

Comment: the code that you removed, it used to control a TFT screen, do you have a TFT scren on your system ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to surround your serialEvent method body in try-catch:

```
void serialEvent (Serial myPort) {

  try {
    ...
    your code
    ...
  }
  catch(RuntimeException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

}
```

There is probably an exception thrown from your serialEvent implementation.

Comment: e.printStactTrace() should be e.printStackTrace()

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside the draw() function, and just use serialEvent() to change the value of variables (remember to initialize them).

Make inStr a global variable. You can define its length and initialize it maybe with 0.

It should be something like:

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;        // The serial port
int[] inStr = {0, 0};

void setup () {
  size(1043, 102);
  background(255);
  myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[1], 9600);
  println(Serial.list());
  myPort.bufferUntil('\n');
}

void draw () {
  fill(0);
  rect(10, 2, inStr[0], 46);

  rect(10, 52, inStr[1], 46);

  fill(255);
  rect(400, 14, 245, 21);

  fill(0);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  textSize(14);
  text("1st value: " + inStr[0] + " 2nd value: " + inStr[1], width/2, 30);
}

void serialEvent (Serial myPort) {
  String inString = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');
  if (inString != null) {
    inString = trim(inString);
    inStr = int(split(inString, '-'));
    println(inStr);
  }
}
```

In the future, try not to use serialEvent to do the work of draw().

Answer (score 0):

```
// At the top of the program:
float xPos = 400; // Horizontal position of the graph
float yPos = 300; // Vertical position of the graph
float zPos = 300;
float regiypos = yPos;
float regizpos = zPos;
int par = 5;

import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort;        // The serial port

int lf = 10;    // Linefeed in ASCII
String myString = null;
float num;

void setup () {

  size(800, 600);        // (Width, Height) window size

  myPort = new Serial(this, "COM4", 115200);

  background(#081640);
  noLoop();  //-- Ne fussál folyamatosan
}

void draw () {
  // Draw the line in a pretty color:
  stroke(#A8D9A7);
  line(xPos-par, regiypos, xPos, yPos);  // (x1, y1, x2, y2) Origó a bal felső sarokban
  regiypos = yPos;                       // ami most új volt azt megőrzi, hogy legyen mivel összekötni

  stroke(#ff00A7);
  line(xPos-par, regizpos, xPos, zPos);
  regizpos = zPos;

  // At the edge of the screen, go back to the beginning:
  if (xPos >= width) {
    xPos = 0;
    // Clear the screen by resetting the background:
    background(#EDA430);
    background(#081640);
  }
  else {
    // Increment the horizontal position for the next reading:
    xPos += par;
  }
}

void serialEvent (Serial myPort) {  // -- Nem fut folyamatosan, hanem csak akkor ha adat érkezik, mert akkor meghívodik ez a fv.

  // Get the byte:
  //   float inByte = myPort.read();
  //   print it:
  //   println(inByte);
  myString = myPort.readStringUntil(lf);
  if (myString != null) {
    print(myString);  // Prints String
    String[] q = splitTokens(myString, ":");
    if (q.length == 2) {
      print(q[0]);  // Acceltoroll print
      print(q[1]);  // Gyrotoroll print

      num = float(q[0]);  // Converts and prints float
      yPos = height/2 - num;
      num = float(q[1]);  // Converts and prints float
      zPos = height/2 - num;
      redraw();             // -- Melynek a végén van a redraw() parancs, mely egyszer lefutattaja a draw()-ban lévő részt.
    }
  }
}
```

And the highlighted part is this:

```
if (q.length == 2) {

  print(q[0]);  // Acceltoroll print
  print(q[1]);  // Gyrotoroll print

  num = float(q[0]);  // Converts and prints float
  yPos = height/2 - num;
  num = float(q[1]);  // Converts and prints float
  zPos = height/2 - num;
  redraw();           // -- Melynek a végén van a redraw() parancs, mely egyszer lefutattaja a draw()-ban lévő részt.
}
```

This will solve your problem. The problem is that q[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) may not exist if the buffer is full and begins to overwrite the data...

Just paste the code to [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) to get a better view.