# Arduino + Proccesing code error “disabling_serialevent()”

Tags: java, arduino, serial-port, processing

I have some problems in my code. I can’t run it, because I always get this error message:

> Error, disabling serialEvent() for COM3 null

#### Code

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial port;
String c = " ";
String d = " ";
String data = " ";
PFont font;
int index = 0;

void setup() {
    size(2024, 1024);
    port = new Serial(this, "COM3", 9600);

    port.bufferUntil('.');
    font = loadFont("run.vlw");
    textFont(font, 60);
}

void draw() {
    background(150, 50, 200);
    fill(46, 20, 2);
    text(c, 70, 175);
    fill(46, 20, 2);
    text(d, 70, 215);
}

void serialEvent(Serial port) {
    data = port.readStringUntil('.');
    data = data.substring(0, data.length() - 1);
    index = data.indexOf(",");
    c = data.substring(0, index);
    d = data.substring(index + 1, data.length());
}
```

Comment: COM port is correct? Maybe try `Serial.list()[0]` as port? Also http://stackoverflow.com/a/26225342/5296568 suggests you should wrap your code inside `serialEvent` in a `try-catch` so that you notice any runtime errors. It maybe seems like an exception is thrown within your `serialEvent` function.

Answer (score 0):

Your `serialEvent()` code doesn't handle exceptions. It is likely that your handling of the serial data contains an error which subsequently causes an unhandled `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`, so the program crashes. To be sure, we would need knowledge of the actual data that gets transmitted via `COM3`.

A suggestion is:

Put the whole code inside of `serialEvent()` in a `try`/`catch` block and print out the exception's stack trace. This should give you more hints about what causes the crash.