# Arduino and Processing code error "disabling serialEvent()"

Tags: java, c++, arduino, serial-port, processing

I am facing the following error in [Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28programming_language%29).

I'm using Windows 10, Processing version 3.5.4, and Arduino version 1.8.16.

> Error, disabling serialEvent() for COM3
> null

Processing code:

```
import processing.serial.*;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
Serial MyPort;
String KeyString = "";

void setup()
{
  System.out.println("HI");
  size(700, 500);
  MyPort = new Serial(this, "COM3", 9600);
  MyPort.bufferUntil('\n');
}

void draw() {
  background(0, 0, 0);
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  text("Press any key", 100, 175);
}

void serialEvent(Serial MyPort)throws Exception {
   KeyString = MyPort.readStringUntil('\n');
   KeyString = KeyString.substring(0, KeyString.indexOf(':'));
   System.out.println(KeyString);
   Robot Arduino = new Robot();

   switch(KeyString) {

     case "Up":
       Arduino.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
       Arduino.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
       break;

     case "Down":
       Arduino.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
       Arduino.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
       break;

     case "Left":
       Arduino.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
       Arduino.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
       break;

     case "Right":
       Arduino.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
       Arduino.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
       break;
   }

}
```

Or is there a way to control the buttons (up, down, left, right, any...)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arduino and Processing Code Error "disabling\_serialevent()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070466/arduino-and-processing-code-error-disabling-serialevent)

Comment: i tried but it doesn't work

Comment: There are plenty of duplicates for this problem (that probably has the same reason). What is the canonical question?

Answer (score 0):

That error occurs whenever an exception is thrown within the method.

You've chosen not to handle exceptions when creating the `Robot` instance.

I recommend initialising `Robot` once in setup rather than over and over again (whenever there's a new serial message).
Additionally, it might help to use [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) such as reserving `TitleCase` for class names and `camelCase` for instance names.

The main error is probably with this line though:

```
KeyString = KeyString.substring(0, KeyString.indexOf(':'));
```

This is optimistically assuming there are absolutely no errors with serial communication and the always is a `:` character. If something goes wrong and the string either split or empty, `indexOf(':')` will return -1 (not found) which makes `.substring(0, -1)` and illegal character index range.

Here's a modified version of your code with above suggestions applied:

```java
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

import processing.serial.*;

// Arduino serial port
Serial arduino;
// input string from Arduino
String keyString = "";
// keyboard shortcut trigger
Robot keyboard;

void setup()
{
  println("HI");
  size(700, 500);

  try{
    arduino = new Serial(this, "COM3", 9600);
    arduino.bufferUntil('\n');
  }catch(Exception e){
    println("error setting up Arduino: double check the port name is correct, present in Device Manager and not used by other apps (e.g. Serial Monitor)");
    e.printStackTrace();
    exit();
  }

  try{
   keyboard = new Robot();
  }catch(Exception e){
    println("Error setting up Robot keyboard trigger");
    exit();
  }

}
void draw(){
  background(0, 0, 0);
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  text("Press any key", 100, 175);
}

void serialEvent(Serial arduino) {
  keyString = arduino.readString('\n');
  // handle edge case
  if(keyString == null){
    // optional: println("null string: skipping")
    return;
  }
  // remove any whitespace
  keyString.trim();
  if(keyString.isEmpty()){
    // optional: println("read empty string: skipping")
    return;
  }

  // extract 1st section until ':'
  int separatorIndex = keyString.indexOf(':');
  if(separatorIndex < 0){
    // optional: println("no ':' found: skipping")
    return;
  }

  keyString = keyString.substring(0, separatorIndex);
  println(keyString);

  switch(keyString){
    case "Up" :
      keyboard.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
      keyboard.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
      break;
    case "Down" :
      keyboard.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
      keyboard.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
      break;
    case "Left" :
      keyboard.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
      keyboard.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
      break;
    case "Right" :
      keyboard.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
      keyboard.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
      break;
  }

}
```

I would also double check test the `keyPress()/keyRelease()` calls in isolation to ensure that the above code will work as intended (and won't require a delay between press and release).

If you simply to need to send a keypress you can send a single byte(value from 0-255). The actual `keyCode` for the arrow keys are 37(left), 38(up), 39(right), 40(down) so you could do send this from Arduino:

```
Serial.write(38);
```

and on the Processing side read a single byte and check it's value.
Remember that in Java a byte is from -127 to 128 instead of 0-255, so you'd need to mask it, for example:

```
if(arduino.read() & 0xFF == 38) println("up");
```

Also note that there are other microcontrollers that could work as HID device (e.g., USB keyboard or mouse) instead of serial port. [Makey Makey](https://makeymakey.com/) is a cute example of that, but there are also Arduino boards using the [ATmega32U4](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATmega32U4) chip which can act as HID device (e.g., [Arduino Leonardo](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-leonardo-with-headers), 32U4 breakouts, etc.).
For this, check out the [Keyboard Arduino Reference](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/usb/keyboard/).

The advantage of this option would be simplicity: one less failure point (the serial communication software to trigger the keypresses).
This disadvantage would be sending additional data. For example, if you need to send some extra values/data after the ':' that won't be straightforward to replace with keypresses.